# Do number of destructors of class depend on the number of overloaded functions

Tags: c++

In a very recent interview, I have faced a following question.

There is a class Foo. In which there are three functions over loaded.

```
class Foo
{
public:
   int Sum(int,int);
   double Sum(int,int);
   int Sum(int,double);
};
```

Question was that, How many destructors have to be written for this class.

I wonder, if this question is correct or not (Any way, one has to be written, on will). I believe that this question is wrong, Did asked the same to interviewer. He said that the question is correct.

Is this really a correct question?

Comment: A class always has one destructor. How many have to be written? None.

Comment: The question is not wrong, but rather the answer is no. If you said yes, I probably wouldn't count on getting the job. Unless I'm way off and missing something, in which case, I wouldn't count on myself getting the job :P

Comment: And I'd bet the question was around 'three overloaded constructors', not 'functions'.

Comment: BTW, the overload of `sum` are not valid, first two have same parameters.

Comment: This may be a trap question. The overloaded function is not valid as pointed out by @billz. If the definition is valid, the answer is zero, because c++ automatically generate destructor, so it is not necessary to write one. Although this seems simple, it may be the start of a series of question related to destructors.

If you find something wrong with the interview question, don't be afraid to point out the errors specifically because they may expect you to do that.

Comment: @chris: "None" - that depends on your notion of "have to"... some classes would leak resources without an explicitly provided destructor (e.g. a smart pointer class).  Of course it's "None" for the class in the question, but your "A class always has" talks about classes in general....

Comment: @TonyD, Good point about moving from general to specific. Even answering for this class is kind of iffy considering it won't compile as is.

Comment: @Praneeth: all you can do with a question like this is explain the situation... points worth making are that the class has no data members to clean up, and isn't currently providing any kind of observer notification, deregistration, logging, so there's ostensibly no reason to add a destructor.  There's no reason to think that the functions (even if the `int`,`int` list didn't clash) have any bearing on the need for a destructor.  They may be deliberately asking a stupid question just to see if it "shakes you up", or in some kind of panic you say something silly and/or erroneous.

Comment: I think the interviewer expected you to say "None. Exactly." I think the interviewer tested you..

Comment: The expected answer would be: "Whoo, you can't overload that just by return value!"

Comment: Correct answer would be none, and extra points for pointing out the illegal overloading

Answer (score 0):

What you meant by "correct question" and what the interviewer did were probably different things.  You wondered whether the question was reasonable, he responded that no, he didn't stumble over explaining the question, which was intended to be confusing.

You probably should have said that (ignoring the illegal overloading) the class has one destructor, provided by the compiler, and the compiler-provided one is good enough so there's no need to write one by hand.

If this was just a snippet taken from code including other classes and inheritance, or any of the member functions were `virtual`, then you should have discussed advantages and conditions of a virtual destructor.